# PHP Switch Case - keeping option selected

Tags: php, select, switch-statement

I tried multiple different answers suggested on here but all does not seem to work with what I am trying to get done.

I am trying to set the option in the select box to selected when picking out the option and submitting it.

I am using switch case because it seems a quicker way to program as oppose to if else statement.

I have iframe on the page. All the targeted links works according to the option but if I try to echo the option that is selected, it will only show the last option selected because it is currently selecting all of my options and that is not what I want.

Here is my code:

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['listings'])){
        $listings = $_POST['listings'];
    } else if (isset($_GET['listings'])) {
        $listings = $_GET['listings'];
    } else {
        $listings = 'chooseListing';
    }

    switch ($listings) {
        case 'captivaCondo':
            $iframe = 'http://sancapmls.com/san/idx/index.php?key=09b24ea58e44d14f9f5efed2bfd1edb2';
            $selected = 'selected';
            break;
        case 'captivaResidential':
            $iframe = 'http://sancapmls.com/san/idx/index.php?key=90f72cf9a9a8fe486dff35cede5208b1';
            $selected = 'selected';
            break;
        case 'sanibelCondo':
            $iframe = 'http://sancapmls.com/san/idx/index.php?key=2282d6f0deb849d6a4915685b7677848';
            $selected = 'selected';
            break;
        case 'sanibelResidential':
            $iframe = 'http://sancapmls.com/san/idx/index.php?key=ceb9ec5fc169c6405d234e9b361f8915';
            $selected = 'selected';
            break;
        case 'choose':
            $iframe = 'choose.php';
            $selected = 'selected';
            break;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <!-- Search Button -->
    <div class="row">
        <form role="form">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select name="listings" class="form-control input-lg">
                <option value="choose">Choose an option</option>
                <option value="captivaCondo">Captiva Condo</option>
                <option value="captivaResidential">Captiva Residential</option>
                <option value="sanibelCondo">Sanibel Condo</option>
                <option value="sanibelResidential">Sanibel Residential</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
    <br>
<!-- iFrame -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <iframe src="<?php echo $iframe; ?>"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
```

Any help and guide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you're never setting the `selected="selected"` in your html

Comment: shouldn't `case 'choose'` be `case 'chooseListing'`?

Comment: The `$selected` variable does not seem to be getting used.  You need to have your switch set a variable that will differentiate which option you chose and then add the `selected="selected"` attribute to the correction `<option>` element.

Comment: I did add it to my html few times but ended up taking it out because it was setting all of my options to selected. That is the reason why it is not in my HTML part. I was trying to figure out where or what I was supposed to put in HTML or if I needed to change my PHP code.

Comment: thats becuase you use the same variable called $selected for each one give each case a different selected variable name then echo out that specific variable name for each option only and it'll work then

Comment: Dave, it worked but now it is giving the output of 'Notice: Undefined Variable" in my select dropdown list. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit dirty, but it should solve your issue.  Start by removing the `$selected` variable from your switch.  It isn't needed.  Instead let's use the `switch` to set the URL for your `iframe` and leave it at that.

```
if (isset($_POST['listings'])){
    $listings = $_POST['listings'];
} else if (isset($_GET['listings'])) {
    $listings = $_GET['listings'];
} else {
    $listings = 'chooseListing';
}

switch ($listings) {
    case 'captivaCondo':
        $iframe = 'http://sancapmls.com/san/idx/index.php?key=09b24ea58e44d14f9f5efed2bfd1edb2';
        break;
    case 'captivaResidential':
        $iframe = 'http://sancapmls.com/san/idx/index.php?key=90f72cf9a9a8fe486dff35cede5208b1';
        break;
    case 'sanibelCondo':
        $iframe = 'http://sancapmls.com/san/idx/index.php?key=2282d6f0deb849d6a4915685b7677848';
        break;
    case 'sanibelResidential':
        $iframe = 'http://sancapmls.com/san/idx/index.php?key=ceb9ec5fc169c6405d234e9b361f8915';
        break;
    case 'choose':
        $iframe = 'choose.php';
        break;
}
```

Now let's add a conditional in your `<option>` elements to put in the `selected="selected"` atrribute:

```
<select name="listings" class="form-control input-lg">
     <option value="choose">Choose an option</option>
     <option value="captivaCondo" <?php if($listings == "captivaCondo") print('selected="selected"'); ?> >Captiva Condo</option>
     <option value="captivaResidential" <?php if($listings == "captivaResidential") print('selected="selected"'); ?> >Captiva Residential</option>
     <option value="sanibelCondo"  <?php if($listings == "sanibelCondo") print('selected="selected"'); ?> >Sanibel Condo</option>
     <option value="sanibelResidential" <?php if($listings == "sanibelResidential") print('selected="selected"'); ?> >Sanibel Residential</option>
</select>
```

It isn't perfect, but it should help you out as a decent start.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: i.e You need add `selected` in html `<option>` tag like `<option value="Your vale" selected='selected'>Your text</option>`

```
    if (isset($_POST['listings'])){
        $listings = $_POST['listings'];
   } else if (isset($_GET['listings'])) {
        $listings = $_GET['listings'];
   } else {
        $listings = 'choose';
   }


      <?php $listingsOptions =  array('choose'=>'Choose an option', 'captivaCondo'=>'captivaCondo', ......);

        <select name="listings" class="form-control input-lg">
           <?php foreach($listingsOptions as $key=>$listing):?>
              <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if($listings==$key): echo  "selected = 'selected'" ; endif; ?> ><?php echo $listing;?></option>
          <?php endforeach;?>
         </select>
```

instead of

```
         <select name="listings" class="form-control input-lg">
            <option value="choose">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="captivaCondo">Captiva Condo</option>
            <option value="captivaResidential">Captiva Residential</option>
            <option value="sanibelCondo">Sanibel Condo</option>
            <option value="sanibelResidential">Sanibel Residential</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: I tried your way and it is still setting all of my options to selected instead of choosing the value and set that option to selected.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check, there is no need of switch case statement.